# PHPstorm: "Project components were changed externally and can not be reloaded"

Tags: php, git

When I switch between branches in PHPstorm I constantly get the following message:

> Project components were changed externally and can not be
>   reloaded: ChangeListManager ToolWindowManager editorHistoryManager
>   FileEditorManager"
>
> Would you like to reload the project?

How to avoid this error?

Comment: Invalidate cache & restart?

Comment: @HendraNucleo I was also going to say restart. How does one invalidate the cache?

Comment: File -> Invalidate cache/Restart -> Invalidate and Restart on menu if you mean so?

Comment: Do you have the `.idea` directory in your `.gitignore`?  If your branch switches are changing files in there it would do what you're describing.

Comment: @GentlemanMax Here is my .gitignore - http://i.imgur.com/6A1owx5.png, but I still get this when I switch branches - http://i.imgur.com/aTfElxU.png

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments.

The solution was the following:

1. Delete `.git`
2. Add `.idea` to `.gitignore`
3. Then `git -init`